# Mapping a block JavaScript code to run only on a specific pages

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am currently using webpack to bundle all my .js into one app.js, thats used in all page on my project.
I have been experiencing a problem however, where code meant for one page is interfering in another page ( where is not needed )!
Like event listeners on a selector will fired on other pages if same selector exists!

Please how can I make specific code on an application run on specific pages, when using one JavaScript file throughout the app?

Comment: If you’re using something like react, then you can add the event handlers in componentDidMount and remove them in componentWillUnmount

Comment: No it’s not a react app!

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Like how you’re moving through pages? If at any time, you know which page you’re navigating to, you could conditionally set or under the event handlers

Comment: I might scope the JS to a body class. Sniffing out the current path to the page via `window.location` but file names might change or get moved so it's a little more brittle than a body class.

Comment: create separate bundles for different pages. There's no point of sending useless code to a user. And use more specific selectors to avoid clashes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `window.location.pathname` to get the url of the page

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
if (filename == 'thepageyouwant') [
  // run your javascript
}
```